# Can't get Ubuntu virtual machine connected to virtual router through VMware

Tags: networking, ubuntu, wireless-networking, router, pfsense

I'm running a virtual router through VMware that has a two virtual NICS connected to it. A bridged NIC for the WAN side to connect directly to the internet and a NIC for the LAN side. I have two Windows VM machines connected to the LAN NIC and they work fine. The ubuntu workstation can't seem to get a outside connection to the internet, ping the gateway, or ping any other internal devices on the network. What's odd though is the Ubuntu is getting DHCP just fine, the router is saying it's giving an address to the Ubuntu box.

Answer (score 0):

If your Windows can go out to the internet your router seems to be configured well.

As I can see the tags of your post you have a pfsense as "virtual router".

pfsense works perfectly after deployment without any further configuration so I assume you did not modify anything in the router.

To be sure open console from the hypervisor where you can see the menu of pfsense and choose option 7 (ping).

[pfsense option seventh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HobDz.jpg)

Type 8.8.8.8 and hit the Enter and validate that ping works.
(If ping does not work your pfsense has no internet connection than fix it - thats a different topic.)

Lets focus on Ubuntu guest now. DHCP was mentioned too. I suggest disable DHCP in Ubuntu and configure Ubuntu's NIC manually. IP/Subnet/Gw enough and ping 8.8.8.8.

If ping traffic goes your Ubuntu is able to go out on WAN interface of your pfsense.

(Because there was no an implicit question the best I can do here suggesting to go through this troubleshoot.)